# Is there a way to extract text from a pdf inside of a Dropbox file system?

Tags: java, pdf, dropbox-api

I am working on a project where I need to iterate through a file system, extract text from a pdf, and scan through that text. Previously, the file system was an N drive (which acts as a local file system), so using the java File API, I could access each pdf file. Using this method, I would then extract the text:

```
public static String returnStringOfPDFiText(File file)
    {
        try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.getPath());
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        String pdfText = null;
        for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            pdfText += PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, n);
        }
        reader.close();
            System.out.println(pdfText);
            
            
            return pdfText;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

From here, I could scan through the text.

I now need to do this, but using a dropbox file system. I can only find a way to get the metadata of each file, though, and not the actual file, so I can extract text.

Is there a way to get the file so I can call this method on the file to extract the text, or to just extract the text directly from the dropbox file?

Edit: I am working with the DropboxAPI already (though I might be missing some methods, I haven't read through a lot of the documentation). I am aware of the download method, but I don't want to use it, since we will be working with around 1 gb of pdfs, and downloading it would be super inefficient.

Comment: I would assume that a file hosting service offers you programmatic APIs that allow you to also download the content of a file. So, what documentation have you been looking at? https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#dropbox-for-java-tutorial for starters, respectively their complete javadoc for their APIs?

Comment: Also note: your problem has actually NOTHING to do with the type of file, or what you what you intend to do with that file. You are solely asking about "how to download the CONTENT of a file from dropbox". Has nothing to do with PDF or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does offer an API you can use for listing, uploading, and downloading files, among other operations. You can find everything you need to get started with the Dropbox API, including documentation, tutorials, and SDKs here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

For Java specifically, we recommend you use the official Dropbox Java SDK:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java

To download a file's contents using that, you can use the `download` method:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v5.2.0/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#download(java.lang.String)

You can find an example of that here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/e52fc828c7c753e04c3fa9d47ab6de7e85d000c4/examples/tutorial/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/tutorial/Main.java#L54

Comment: Thank your for this! I am looking for a way other than downloading if possible, since I am working with about 1gb of files, so downloading would be horribly inefficient. Do you know if that exists? Also, other people on other devices would be using it, so I don't want to download a ton of files to their device when they use the program. If another way doesn't exist, I'll have to talk to my manager about creating my own file system, where everything is sorted by file name.

Comment: The [`DbxDownloader`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v5.2.0/com/dropbox/core/DbxDownloader.html) returned by `download` does allow you to access a stream of the bytes, so you don't need to save all of the data to the local filesystem.